# Laravel sort and/or group from relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, eloquent-relationship

In livewire, I'm getting a collection of records ($testItems) from a many-many relation like:

```
---blade---
<livewire:test-items :test="$test"/>

---test model---
public function items ()
    {
        return $this->belongstoMany(item::class);
    }

---livewire component---
render(){
    $testItems = $this->test->items;
    return view ('livewire.test-items',['testItems' => $testItems]);
}

---test-items livewire component blade---
@foreach ($testItems as $testItem)
   <div> {{$testItem->question}}</div>
   <div> {{$testItem->category->name}}</div>
   <div> {{$testItem->answer}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Each item also has other fields like 'category' and I'd like to sort or group the display of these testItems in the component by category.  What's the eloquent syntax for this?

Comment: Grouping on an eloquent query https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping, grouping on a laravel collection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby. Note that doing grouping on a collection is slower than on a query

Comment: I've put orderBy in the model and that seems to be working for now. return $this->belongstoMany(item::class)->orderBy('category_id');  It seems like: $testItems = $this->test->items->sortBy('category_id'); also works.  Thanks for the pointer to the docs.